# Javascript onKeyUp condition doesnt work when speed typing

Tags: javascript, html

my simple html file code

```
Site Name: <input id="name" type="text" onkeyup="myFunction1(event,this)">
URL      : <input id="url" type="text">
```

javascript code

```
function myFunction1(event,t){
     var nameval= document.getElementById("name").value;
     var urlval= document.getElementById("url").value;
     var namelen = nameval.length;
     var urllen = urlval.length;
     var res = nameval.substring(1, namelen);

     if(res.length == urllen){
            document.getElementById("url").value = t.value;
     }
     else{
            alert("string lengths are not matching");
     }
}
```

what i want to do when user type Site Name in textbox, same text should reflect to URL textbox if name and url text boxes have same text lenghts . but when i speed type site name, my if condition fail after typing few characters and it goes to else block. i dont know why this happening. can anyone help me to improve this code?

Comment: There's no need to request #name if you already sent the reference as t in  the parameter. Also, the error is because of the type of event (keyup), sometimes when you type fast you are hitting the next letter without releasing the prior keystroke.

Comment: so what kind of solution that i can apply

Answer (score 1):

Using the *onkeyup* event isn't your best option for what you are trying to do. You can use the *oninput* event instead. Here's the modified HTML:

```
Site Name: <input id="name" type="text" oninput="myFunction1(event,this)">
URL      : <input id="url" type="text">
```

Comment: Are you sure? I put all the files into jsfiddle and it does work: https://jsfiddle.net/ckzkgjjn/